# Is there a place on SO to get help writing questions?

Tags: support

I'm having trouble writing a question. The topic includes common words which could have many meanings. I haven't been able to come up with the right words to make clear what I'm asking. For example: Safari occasionally rings a loud, obnoxious bell. I want it to stop doing that, but can't find how to turn it off in Safari. Is there a place on SO where I could get help choosing good words?

--

I agree that the question about Safari is more a user question than a programming question. However, the meta part -- is there a place to get help formulating questions? -- is still something I'd like to know about.

Comment: Well, that doesn't sound like a programming question, and so wouldn't belong on SO to begin with...

Comment: From that description I would say it is more suited for SuperUser.com... try a chat room first...

Comment: [Hmm, I wonder how we could help in these situations...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212385/translation-help-review-queue)

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of things that make a good question. In order they are:

- choose the right site for it. A programming question belongs on SO. A question about using a program you didn't write does not. Neither does a design question or a cooking question. If you ask a question on the wrong site it **might** get migrated, but don't count on it. You pretty much have to get this right in order to get any answers.
- give it the right tags. Most users follow tags they care about. If you want to know about sorting in C# but you only tag it `sorting`, less people will see it. If you tag it `C++` just in the hope that lots of smart people see it, but it has no C++ content, you will be sorry.
- have an actual question. **How Do I ... ?** or *What causes this error?* or **Why is my output wrong?**. Not `any clue?` or `I would be grateful for any advice` or any other vague begging for help. Ask a **question**. [see  note below]
- include what people need to answer you. If people ask for more in the comments, edit it into the question
- use good grammar, spelling, and punctuation
- organize the question sensibly

The further down this list you go the higher the chances someone can do it for you. When that happens **learn from it.** If the question is better now, you have learned a general rule about making questions better.

Practice makes perfect. Get the site and tags right, and then practice! And let us help you, we're generally hard to stop anyway.

Note: the third bullet has an interesting effect for many people. They are at "what the heck? why can't I do this? I don't get it!" but that's not a question. So they set to work trying to write an actual, you know, *question*. And as they try to make it crisper - is the problem this compiler error, or that bad output, or not knowing what parameter 3 is? - and put together an example that demonstrates it without pasting in 1000 lines of code, they suddenly realize they know what the problem is, and they solve it themselves. The rigour and structure of writing an actual question is valuable on its own. And of course if you don't solve it yourself, you have a well written question to ask.

Comment: The "learn from it" is a *very* important thing.  Someone did a review of the question and fixed some/most/all the errors (punctuation, spelling, grammar, formatting, etc...).  Being able to write your next question using this additional knowledge will make it easier for you to communicate your question in the first place in a way that people are more likely to find clear (and more likely to answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you just write your question, than people might edit the question to make more sense, or they will leave comments on your question asking for clarification.

You can use these comments to guide you in improving your question.

Even if your question gets closed in the meantime, you can nominate it for reopening when you feel that it is sufficiently improved.  If it truly is a good question by then, people will probably vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Not everyone is a good question writer at first. So what can you do?

### Improve it!

After asking a question it is very important to stay put, answer to comments and improve your post according to it. Your average post may become a very good one due to this process.