# Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, faq, languages, non-english-speakers, english

Otherwise known as

- 必须用英语吗？(is English required?)
- ¿Necesito hablar en inglés?
- ?האם אני חייב לכתוב באנגלית
- Muss ich auf Englisch schreiben?
- 英語で書かなければなりませんか?

Do I have to use English when posting a question, an answer or a comment on a Stack Exchange site?

[Return to FAQ Index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/)

Answer (score 352):

**tl;dr:** Unless you're posting on a language-related site (e.g. French Language) or a site where all questions are expected to be in a different language (e.g. Stack Overflow in Spanish), yes, all posts are expected to be in English. A special case exists for the Russian language; see below.

---

### What is the *official* policy in simple terms?

The Stack Exchange Trilogy has an [official policy on non-English questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) (please feel free to read the full blog post for more detail):

> **It is not, nor has it ever been, our goal to be the one place in the world for all programming information in *every possible human language*.**
>
> - **Direct question posters to native language resources.**
> - **It is not the community's goal to teach English.**
> - **The question asker should put some effort into the question.**

As long as the question is in salvageable English and makes some modicum of sense, it should be edited and improved like any other post.

### Why have an English-only policy?

[Languages by total number of speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers)

[image]

**English is as close that we have ever come to a global lingua-franca**.  It is generally considered the dominant language of science and diplomacy.  It is also the most taught second-language by a far, far margin.  English is the [official language](http://encyclopedia2.tfd.com/English+language) of about 45 nations.

> English is everywhere. Some 380 million people speak it as their first language and another 600 million speak it as their second. A billion are learning it, about a third of the world's population is in some sense exposed to it and by 2030, it is predicted almost half of the world will be more or less proficient in it. It is the language of globalization - of international business, politics and diplomacy. It is the language of computers and the Internet. You'll see it on posters in Beijing, you'll hear it in pop songs in Tokyo, you'll read it in official documents in Prague. Deutsche Welle broadcasts in it. Bjork, an Icelander, sings in it. French business schools teach in it. It is the medium of expression in cabinet meetings in Bolivia. English is now the global language.  - [Oxford Seminars](http://www.oxfordseminars.com/Tesol/Pages/Teach/teach_20000jobs.php)

The number of people who speak English is nowhere near as important as how many people can write it.  More specifically, the number of people who use their written language on the Internet can be the single most telling piece of information. **The #1 language of the Internet is English**, by a wide margin.  In the chart below you can see that it is almost three times as prolific as the next language.

> Global Internet Usage
> [Language - Number of users (millions)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_internet_usage)
>
> **English  - 295.2**
> Chinese  - 110.0
> Spanish  - 86.0

Finally, **most programming languages are based in English**.  Their keywords, APIs, and documentation are mostly taken from English words.  The number of mainstream languages that have non-English language equivalents are [few and far between](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English-based_programming_languages).  With our languages already based in English, it makes sense to continue expanding our knowledge repository without dividing it into various inaccessible fractions.

### Are there any exceptions?

Sure! On language-related sites, [you are allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278299/350567) to use those languages in addition to English. They are:

- [Chinese Language](https://chinese.stackexchange.com)
- [Esperanto Language](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com)
- [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com)
- [German Language](https://german.stackexchange.com)
- [Italian Language](https://italian.stackexchange.com)
- [Korean Language](https://korean.stackexchange.com)
- [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com)
- [Latin Language](https://latin.stackexchange.com)
- [Portuguese Language](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com)
- [Russian Language](https://russian.stackexchange.com)*
- [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com)
- [Ukrainian Language](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com)

<sup>* There's a special site for full-Russian. See below.</sup>

### Are there any Stack Exchange sites completely in other languages?

Yes. There *are* a few! While we are *currently not* accepting proposals for *new* non-English sites, these existing sites are available for anyone interested in those languages:

- Stack Overflow in Japanese: [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://jp.stackoverflow.com)
- Stack Overflow in Portuguese: [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com)
- Stack Overflow in Russian: [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)
- Stack Overflow in Spanish: [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com)
- Russian Language in Russian: [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com)

### What should I do if someone else makes a post that is not in English?

If someone makes a non-English post on a site other than one in the above two lists, or in a language different from the site's accepted languages, first, check to see if it's spam. A small portion of wrong-language posts are actually spam, so be sure to check for that.

If it's not spam, vote or flag to close it as "Needs details or clarity" if it's a question, or flag as "very low quality" if it's an answer.

**Do not translate wrong-language posts.** Machine translations (e.g., Google Translate) can be inaccurate, and even human translations risk distorting the intended meaning of the post. It's up to the author to make sure that their post fits the quality standards of the site; if they don't, it reduces their chance of getting a good answer (in the case of a question) or that their post will be well-received.

Note that some sites may have different, possibly overriding guidance on moderating wrong-language posts. For example, Stack Overflow [has its own community-specific close reason for wrong-language questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422751/2157772) (but still otherwise follows the general policy above), and Mathematics [allows for translation in certain cases](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35656/what-is-math-ses-policy-on-posts-in-languages-other-than-english).

Comment: It's worthy to note that it's now mandarin that is the most common language.

Comment: Yes, but probably due to population bias when considering those percentages... besides the fact that it is *like* a lingua franca plus most code being written in English.

Comment: The link to Oxford Seminars is broken (apparently for long as [no valid archive is available](https://web.archive.org/web/20150701000000*/http://www.oxfordseminars.com/Tesol/Pages/Teach/teach_20000jobs.php). I found [6 Reasons to Choose Oxford Seminars](https://www.oxfordseminars.com/blog/6-reasons-to-choose-oxford-seminars/) with the same quote, but this article really looks like an advertisement, and does not cite any external source.

Comment: PunjabiGerman is considered a quasi-extinct language.

Comment: The statistics number seems quite old and no longer accurate now. But I understand the fact that English world and culture cultivated StackOverflow and StackExchange.  i.e. the creator of SE speak English, and want to keep it.

Comment: "English is as close that we have ever come to a global lingua-franca..." and the following defense of choosing English is irrelevant. It's a legacy product/design choice. If Chinese becomes the most common language in computing, is SE going to become Chinese-only? I doubt it.

Comment: Why not translate wrong-language posts? My edits often involve fixing broken English; how is translation any different?

Comment: @BrianDrake It is explained in the [SO FAQ for non-English posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/8376184) (tl;dr: the OP can't understand the answers & can't respond). However, an OP with bad English can still somehow communicate and understand the responses they got.

Comment: What is the scope of this English-only policy? The answer (and the linked blog post) both say that the SE Trilogy (which apparently encompasses Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User) has an English-only policy. But then they go on to list "exceptions to the English-only policy", kind of implying that the English-only policy applies much more broadly to all sites in the network by default. This leaves me very confused about whether the English-only policy applies to most sites (those not listed as exceptions) or to just a few sites (the "trilogy" sites). Which is it?

Comment: Hindustani! Oh dear god! There's no such language in existence. Did you mean Hindi? (And not everyone in India speaks Hindi btw) :)

Comment: @TimCampion yes, all SE sites are English-only by default, with the exception of language sites (SE sites about non-English languages) and localized sites (SE sites with non-English UI. English posts are off-topic there).

Comment: To the development team of all stackexchange sites: how about a simple button to switch languages? Someone could add an answer/question in addition to the english version but not all would be shown at the same time. This could help many while keeping the noDuplicate-goal?!

Comment: @intijk it's less about culture and more about practicality - the post above says that many programming languages depend on English (key)words, true, but even worse than that: mainstream operating systems (i.e. programming environments) also rely heavily on english (so it's not just the programming language) AND some programming (language) concepts are also dependent on english (and sometimes culture), consider for example metaphors.

I've seen many language-related coding mistakes in my life to strongly advise a minimum understanding of english before any serious programming.

Comment: Note: per [KyleMit's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423586/1478931) to the MSO request [Reject question titles with no English letters in them, warn about titles with too few a-z compared to other letters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390146/1478931), we've added a new question title validation that titles must have at least one character between a-z; it's active on all sites except a few. (Most of the exceptions are the international SO sites, as well as some SE sites about languages that aren't written using Latin script – plus a few others.)

Comment: @V2Blast Is the filter also active on Mathematics? Based on a recent [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35615) that came up on the local meta, it seems that the site policy there is to accept questions in languages other than English.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Yes, the filter is indeed active there. That seems to be a somewhat odd local policy, given that there's no one other language that folks could reasonably be expected to know (unlike on the language-related sites) – though I can understand if that "policy" just means they'll translate stuff for users rather than expecting them to know perfect English before they post.

Comment: @V2Blast Thank you for the response! I'll let the moderators there know that such a filter is active on that site, and they may figure out whether any change is needed, in light of their policy on accepting non-English posts. I'm not too sure about the details myself.

Comment: *"It's worthy to note that it's now mandarin that is the most common language"* - this isn't about what language has the most *native* speakers; as a *second* language, English is near-universal. Especially in science/business/international-commerce. Any situation where people from different cultures need to communicate. Look at [second language column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers). No other language is even close, in this sense. It is what it is.