# Idioma de las preguntas, Languages of questions

Tags: discussion, languages

Cualquier idioma en que haga las preguntas será contestada con igual velocidad?
O piensan que algún idioma pueda ser contestado más rápidamente?

Will questions in any language be answered with equal speed?
Or do you believe that some language can be answered more quickly?

Regards,
gab

Comment: Vi verŝajna pli ricevas respondojn por demandoj skriba en Esperanto. Bonvolu ekskuzi mia trandukon malbonan. (You'd likely recieve more answers for questions written in Esperanto. Please excuse my bad translation.)

Comment: si deseas ayuda con programacion en espanol, visita http://www.forosdelweb.com/ (if you want help with programming in spanish, visit that site)

Comment: Ich geb dir zehn Cent, dann kannst du's 'ner Parkuhr erzählen (I think this is a very interesting question)

Comment: This site is for questions in English. (This site is for questions in English.)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 15):

English is the language of computer science.

Comment: This is only true by accident. We could have had French or Russian, depending on which language was the lingua franca or which way the world tilted in terms of its balance of power during the rise of CS.

Comment: +1 because well, I think you deserve it.

Comment: @Max: So?  What *could have happened* doesn't change the facts of what *did happen*.  There seem to be a lot more English speakers (including ESL) among programmers than any other language.  It's just easier to find information if you can communicate in English.

Comment: -1 Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: English also has a much more rich technical vocabulary than most other languages. Which means it is less ambiguous, which means it's easier to write technical documentation in.

Comment: @earlz: English also is considered a "level 8" language while most languages are "level 9" which means English is actually simpler than most of the other languages on this planet which makes it ideal for people from different cultures etc. to communicate among each other.

Answer (score 10):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: -1 The question wasn't "What is the policy?"   Besides, I cut my "critic" teeth on Byron's reply, and I needed to be even handed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a slightly different perspective than Byron --

For the most part, this is an English site, (see Jeff's response) and so, there are more speakers of English on here.  As such, a question in English is more likely to find someone who can both understand the question and provide a useful answer.

If you were on a site that was dominated by a different language, and I've seen discussion sites in Swedish, German, Japanese, Spanish, etc, then asking the question in the language of that site would make the most sense to get the fastest response.

... but then we have to ask if faster is better -- if there was loss of clarity by translating the question, the translated question might be less specific or be misunderstood, and therefore the answers not be useful to the person asking the question.

I personally think you did the right thing by asking in both the language of the local community and your native language.

Comment: +1 But it is interesting that you raise the  "faster vs better" dichotomy.  It appears, de facto, that the SO system often rewards a fast response over  a well considered, high quality reply.  I have no idea what language would facilitate the fastest response among adepts.  Nor do I think that is a particularly useful question.  However, a policy that allowed questions in any language, combined with a way of organizing questions in many languages, may have the potential to produce better answers.  It may even produce better questions.

Answer (score 1):

No.

I think there was something in one of the blog posts about English, and I know there have been endless debates on whether it should be spelled color or colour, but that is not this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

No, solamente serán contestadas aquellas en inglés, el resto será feroz y rapidamente castigada con votación baja y en cuestión de unos minutos será cerrada por aclamación popular.

Hay un creencia ( bien fundada ) de que el inglés es necesario para programar, aunque muchos principiantes no sepan al inicio, ni inglés ni programar y que la carencia de el primero les impida acceder al segundo.

Translation:

English is the lingua franca of programming. :)

Comment: "What took you so long?" "Stutters."

Comment: The previous comment is a reference to the movie *The Court Jester* (quote [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049096/quotes?qt0347309)), in case anyone thought I was insulting the Spanish language.