# Cannot add non-English tags to questions of a foreign-language SE site

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stack-exchange, non-english-speakers

It seems there are no problems with writing questions or answers in non-English languages like Korean (hangul, 한글).  But I can't add non-English tags.  Are there any plans to fix this?  Or is it intentional?

I'm not asking this for Stack Overflow. I've proposed a site in Area 51 that will be mostly for Korean people. So far, this problem is the biggest issue we've found.

Comment: Yes, it is "intentional", because the engine was designed with having English entries only in mind. I doubt that Jeff will "waste" time on this, so be prepared for `status-bydesign`.

Comment: @Ladybug, see OP's comment on my answer.

Comment: @Pop: I know this comment. I added the `Area51` tag.

Comment: @Ladybug, sorry, I missed your quotes.  I need more sleep.

Comment: @Pop: Have a nice nap! :)

Comment: @Ladybug, not in the cards, but thanks for the sentiment.

Comment: @young it is ok to ask these questions here, meta.SO *is* the official area51-meta, mixed up with SE in general and SO, too, unfortunately...

Comment: @LadyBug, @Pop, Thank you for clarifying this question! hope I can get an official answer before more koreans follow the proposed site. :)

Comment: See my comments on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58846/implement-tag-diacritics-with-automatic-synonyms/59169#59169) -- good luck to you on this request. I'd like to see it, but it probably isn't going to happen.

Comment: update: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/add-non-latin-character-set-support-for-tags

Comment: For what it’s worth, I couldn’t even save an edit to this very post without respelling the hangeul using HTML character references. Korean script seems to be banned specifically.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>For better or for worse, English is the official language of Stack Overflow.  Using Unicode to insert Korean text may be technically possible, but it is strongly discouraged.</strike>

There is actually an [official policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) about this.  See also [the relevant FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow).

My answer is no longer relevant based on the OP's comment.  Not deleting the answer to preserve the comment.

Comment: I'm not asking this for StackOverflow. I've proposed one Q/A site through Area 51 for korean people and everything is excellent except for this limitation. Let me edit my question to make it clear.