# Why are diacritics not supported in tags consistently?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, tags, unicode

[Recently, it came up that there does not seem to be a way to support `é` in the tagging syntax.](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3428/can-the-tag-resume-be-changed-to-r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9) This seemed like a bizarre unicode bug at first (something which would be especially bizarre from a company which was founded by Spolsky) but then I ran an experiment. I went to create a question in stackoverflow.com, french.stackexchange.com, and christianity.stackexchange.com.

It should be noted: I have a reputation of over 4k in Christianity, and over 40k in Stackoverflow, so I can create tag synonyms in both. I am not a member of french.stackexchange.com.

I inserted the following into a "new question" (without publishing)

`[tag:résst]` (basically something that looked a little "word-like" which included an `é`)

In Stackoverflow and French, it turned into the tag syntax and highlighted (such as with `[tag:bug]`: [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)), but on this site and Christianity it remained `[tag:résst]`.

Why?

Comment: The reason for the special handling of accented chars was [de-normalization](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/04/technical-debt-case-study-tags.html) and the need to use sql server text search... but based on Marc's blog post I would expect the tags would be handled equally everywhere. Maybe it is a per-site config-setting?

Comment: I added a "bug" tag because, to be honest, failure to support unicode in tagging seems like a major bug, even if it is inexplicably available on some sites..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Non-ASCII characters are enabled in tags on a per-site basis. On most sites, they're disabled; no reason to have a [tag:résumé] tag *and* a [resume](/questions/tagged/resume) tag.

On sites that host a large amount of non-English content, the setting is enabled.

It's also enabled on Stack Overflow, for reasons I cannot begin to fathom. Let's blame tequila. I've turned it off.

Comment: Thank you. Seemed like that was the case, but it is good to have someone be explicit.

Comment: Are you positive that most sites have *zero* need for Non-ASCII symbols? Even on [cs.SE] we could use them because some of our concepts are named after their inventors -- who were quite often French, German, ...

Comment: This is similar to the situation on [cooking.se] and a few other sites, @raphael. The critical factor here is: would you need/want "ascii-clean" versions of these tags *anyway?*

Comment: @Shog9 The idealist in me says "no, why would we?" But I realize that large parts of the user base can not be bothered to use reasonable keyboard layout, so yes, we'd probably want those. But [there are better ways](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58846/156248) to accomodate ASCII-typers besides just forbidding most symbols.

Comment: I think that we should have a [résumé] tag that has a synonym with a [resume] tag. It's the best of both worlds: one tag and we are using proper diacritics.