# Diff highlighting fails on tags with diacritics in suggested edits reviews

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, suggested-edits, localization

This may seem like a ghost edit: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/51233 (SOes).

It turns out the tag `matemáticas` was added as a suggested edit, but it was rendered as:

[image: diff missing in tag matemáticas]

when it should have been:

[image: tag highlighted in green]

The DOM inspector shows:

```html
<a href="/questions/tagged/matem%c3%a1ticas" class="post-tag" title="" rel="tag">matemáticas</a>
```

missing the `<span class="diff-add">` it should have had:

```html
<a href="/questions/tagged/matem%c3%a1ticas" class="post-tag" title="" rel="tag"><span class="diff-add">matemáticas</span></a>
<!--                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^ -->
```

---

I found out this is happening on **all tags with diacritics**: <sup>(*this is enabled [on a per-site basis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270702/304899))</sup>

1. Diff working in the body, failing with tags:
   https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18543 (SOes)
2. Two tags added, only the "*ASCII*" tag is highlighted:
   https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20105 (SOes)
3. Diff works as expected on `/revisions` (no-repro here):
   https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/197/revisions (SOes)
4. Reproduced on different sites:

   - https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12155 (Spanish)
     ([bug report](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/empty-suggested-edit) by @fedorqui)
   - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/116711 (SOpt)
5. This doesn't seem to be an issue with Russian characters:
   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/174038 (RU.SO)

Comment: I originally posted on MSOes (https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2234/127) but I thought it should live here.

Comment: Just curios. What is the meaning of _Rechazar_ ? Is it _Reject_?

Comment: @SagarV yes, it was rejected with the comment "no improvement whatsoever".

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been fixed somewhere in the past:

> [image]

See how "matemáticas" is highlighted, while it was not in the image of the question. That is, the element has now a `<span class="diff-add">` which did not have before.

I checked the rest of the links given in the question. All of them are working well.