# Non English question, answer or comment - should I report?

Tags: support, flags, non-english-speakers

Suppose I stumble upon whole question, answer or comment (not part, the whole post) written in non English language.

Even after reading [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) and [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75091/how-should-we-handle-non-english-answers) I'm still not sure what is the policy or accepted behavior - should I flag the post for moderator attention or leave it be, adding my own comment asking to translate?

(I just did report such a comment, hope it won't hurt my flag weight :))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should report it for moderator attention (and vote to close if you have that ability).  The first link you referenced is the official policy.  This is reinforced by the FAQ for that item: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did - can't vote to close/delete comments though. :)