# What should we do with posts written in a language different  from English?

Tags: support, languages, non-english-speakers, english

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is English required on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow)
>   [Non English question, answer or comment - should I report?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84319/non-english-question-answer-or-comment-should-i-report)

I am not talking about questions in C# and answers in Java. What should we do with posts written in languages that are not English, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841406/cannot-install-mysql2-gem/7860477#7860477) (now deleted)?

Comment: Answer them in different language too?)

Comment: @beryllium - BRILLIANT.

Comment: See also: Stack Overflow's [Non-English Question Policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/).

Comment: Kinda related: [Should multilingual posts be edited to remove non-English content?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109048/should-multilingual-posts-be-edited-to-remove-non-english-content)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the past, I have flagged them for a moderator using the `Other:` reason.  The posts should be closed/temporarily deleted until they are edited.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's just one among many, a comment should  work: Tell them (preferably adding a link) that Stack Overflow uses English. It shouldn't be a serious issue though; much less than 1% of answers are in Spanish.

Personally, I feel we should gently remind people of it, since it is simply really hard for some folks.

Comment: It's an English language site, though.  How can the majority of users evaluate whether the post is spam or offensive if it's in a different language?  I know I wish I were multilingual, but I'm not.

Comment: It's Portuguese actually, but why would it be offensive? Meaning, why assume bad about people(and this is a technical, non-political site also) ?  I just feel we should be gentle to them, rather than abruptly closing...

Comment: There's nothing ungentle about closing a question or deleting an answer.  People read more into those actions than they should.  Most if not all moderators would leave a comment on the deleted answer that still can be read by the user who posted it.

Comment: I'm not saying it's offensive in any way, but aside from using simple heuristics, there's no way for me to tell, in any language I don't know, not just in this case.