# How should we handle wholly non-English comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, languages

Ok, I've read through [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow) and [How should we handle non-English answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75091/how-should-we-handle-non-english-answers). They encourage new posts in just English, but I didn't see a decision about how to handle existing content in other languages.

On one of the Beta SEs, we have a member who semi-regularly posts comments in what I assume to be a dialect from India.  For example, his most recent comment reads as follows:

> gupta ji apne last question pe bhi najar daalo..

Should non-English comments...

- be flagged `not constructive / off topic`?
- be flagged `other` (with a comment)?
- be left as-is?
- be dealt with some other way?

I understand [the official policy is to post questions in English](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/).  What should be done with existing comments that are in other languages?

Comment: It's Hindi for "Mr Gupta, have a look at my last question". I've seen a couple of Hindi comments on [so]. I think it's best to just let him know about the official policy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd flag as "other" and leave a comment. You can also leave a comment explaining the policy to the user.

Answer (score 8):

I'd add a comment explaining that posts on SE sites need to be in english and flag it as "other". Flags are the correct way if you think that a comment should be removed for any reason.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read, my understanding of the matter is that: English should be used. I never saw anywhere where it stated that other languages are not to be used, yet from what I did read is that its just implying that answers should be in English.

With handling comments: If the comment is relevant to the question, and not just some conversation between two people (unfortunately, if we don't know  the language we can't tell what the heck they are talking about ^_^) I would just ignore it... or ask them to translate their comment. Depending on the relevance of the question to my needs.