# Stack Overflow for different speaking languages

Tags: discussion, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is English required on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow)

Is it allowed to use different speaking languages while asking questions? I am asking this question because some of the Area 51 proposals have been specifically for particular speaking languages (ex. Spanish). Is it better to allow & implement speaking language filters? Or any other solution?

This is obvious because not the whole world is better with English still and also lots of grammatical errors being generated while questioning!

Friends, if we go with the strategy of "Question is important, not language", then it is not to start Stack Overflow with different languages, but to solve this issue only! In the sense, everyone can still read the question in English after converting or else other solution!

Comment: Multiple languages for eg. on meta will make meta less attractive to users who don't speak those other languages.  Separate Spanish or other language versions of its main websites is expected(by me) in the future.(Allowing spanish on spanish.SE.com is a different matter.)

Comment: Not all spoken languages can be written, even less can be typed.

Comment: "I am not suggesting to start SO with different languages but discussing only on this speaking language problem." What problem?

Comment: :) I have specified the matter of area51. I thought not to start SO with different speaking languages. But, discussing if any solution with this issue ! (So mentioned only & now edited properly)

Comment: I think allowing a non english stack overflow is counter productive for all programmers in the world, just like having localized IDEs is. If you don't speak english you are in the wrong field and you should really either learn it or change profession.

Comment: Nice approach Kop ! Just suggest this to all those who want to use their local language.

Comment: @Kop I disagree. There is a notable difference between being able to read and  understand literature, and write basic English (which is what I agree every programmer in the world needs)  and interacting with peers in English within a community like SO. The latter is an unrealistic expectation for a vast majority of non-english audiences.

Comment: @Pekka: I don't know if you are a native english speaker or not, but I'm not and I can tell you from first hand experience that non-english literature and communities (such as SO) is of extremely low quality and volume, and as such I think it's better if it was non existent altogether to force people to learn and use English so that they can get better results.

Comment: @Kop I'm not a native speaker. I can confirm your experience in many areas of programming (translated manuals, etc.), and I agree that using english would be preferable for the global programming community. But I don't think it'll work. I have recommended SO to many German friends and colleagues (top-notch developers among them) but except for a few answers here and there, none has really become involved and I think that is mainly due to the language barrier.