# Tag counts should have commas for readability

Tags: feature-request

To me:

```
[tag] × 188,341
```

reads much better than:

```
[tag] × 188341
```

Is it possible for you to update the display, or at least make it an option?

Comment: What about cultures that don't use commas as place value separators? Should this be localized for all of them?

Comment: @TheEstablishment they are already weeping over [the tag pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) anyway... and the top users page... and their rep...

Comment: Related: [Add thousands separators to the numbers of votes and edits displayed on the Users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120971/add-thousands-separators-to-the-numbers-of-votes-and-edits-displayed-on-the-user)

Answer (score -1):

1. Each person have own readability habits
2. You forgot one thing - **it's the whole World outside USA**, and different countries have different regional settings. For me 188,341 may be (in context) *188 items*.

So - or "no-no", or "user-configurable" without locale-guessing from IP or Accepted-Language in browser

Comment: I totally agree, everyone has different readability habits and interprets symbols and numbers different.  However, I did just noticed this though...:  asked 3 years ago
viewed **281,307** times
active 3 months ago - so it should at least be consistent...

Comment: This *is* an American web site, so it would actually be *more* accurate to use the local thousand separator. Of course, if other languages were supported, the separators should reflect that. Also, how can you possibly have decimals in a fundamentally integer quantity?

Comment: @l0b0: you're quite right, you can't have decimal places in an integer quantity.  That's why it shouldn't be written with decimals ;)

Comment: @l0b0: Different Languages and different locales support is not the same.

Comment: And I don't see anywhere that this is an American site. And is it North-American or South-American? Or maybe Central-American site?

Comment: @l0b0 What is going on here? How is this an American web site? Because its servers are hosted in a data center in the USA? So anyone outside of the USA is not welcome to use the site, and if they do, they must tolerate our inconsistent butchering of number formatting (among other things)?