# Display number format of questions asked on tags page

Tags: discussion, tags

On the tags page (https://stackoverflow.com/tags), I was wondering if we could change the format of the numbers displayed by using commas separators. For example, for the c# tag, it's showing

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) x 435081

and I was wondering if it'd be worth considering displaying [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) x 435,081. I think it'd be more readable.

Comment: Related: [Should the network use thousands separators in numbers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148048/should-the-network-use-thousands-separators-in-numbers)

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a few parts of the world where the thousands separator is `.` and the decimal point is `,`.  Omitting the thousands separator avoids having to figure out which separator to use.

Comment: Why choose? Let the code figure it out using the current culture. =)

Comment: There's `,` all over the place already (rep in particular), I don't think that's a real issue.

Comment: When clicking through to a tag page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) theres a comma displayed there, so I think it would make sense for consistency at least.

Comment: Over here the `,` separator is of course called "decimal comma". And the thousands separator is a space. :-)