# To comma or not to comma, that is the question

Tags: feature-request, help-center, wording, numbers

In the [badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) there are lots of numbers on display, including 1000, 2500 or 10000.

The display is erratic though:

> [image]

Same number, two displays.

Both appear valid to me: 1000 or 1,000 but please, make it consistent. My eyes hurt! :)

I just found [this other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148048/152859), but there it's discussing the whole network while I'm asking just for that specific page. For a start.

Comment: Whether 'this nobler in the mind to suffer / The slings and arrows of poor grammar, / Or to take arms against a giant 'S', / And by opposing defeat it

Comment: @Cody very poetic!

Comment: This is exactly the point I made in [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149988/192221) to the post you linked - consistency of *whatever* scheme is chosen is crucial.

Comment: @Duncan true, but I don't think "Asked a question with 10K views" fits in the badges page. The display there should be as simple/friendly as possible.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd My answer was suggesting the implementation of two formatting schemes, the longer-format one could be used whenever required (such as in your example above).

Comment: @Josh let localization handle this, Stack Overflow's official language is English so I don't consider this a problem. :)

Comment: @Josh if you noticed recently there are lots of bugs with HTML showing, or tooltips malformed and you can see the devs commenting it's all due to localizing strings and starting to use templates. So soon there will be Stack Overflow in different languages, and it's very likely to see 10,000 formatted using other culture as well.

Comment: I feel your pain. Or rather, more of a very, very, very mild annoyance.