# Comments hover over reputation - number format

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments, markdown, tooltips

When you hover over the username in comments section, it shows reputation of the user which is great. **My request is: can this number be formatted as it's hard to read for high rep users** (10k+ or especially 100k+)

- display the rep as 33,551 instead of 33551 (my preferred option)
- or alternatively as 33k or 33.5k

A sample screenshot:

[image]

I know it's a small problem but then it won't hurt anyone and should be easy to implement.

**ADDITIONAL REQUEST**

As pointed out by jmac, same same number format and behavior exists when you mouseover someone's rep ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhloC.png)). It would be good to change it there too.

Comment: [highly related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29986/180276)

Comment: Yes, I saw that post but it's not the same.

Comment: You're very right. Sorry for jumping the gun!

Comment: Option 1 sounds good, option 2 would be a major step backwards

Comment: I was actually going to propose this some time ago (specifically: your first bullet), but I put it off and eventually forgot, so +1.

Comment: Note: same same number format and behavior exists when you mouseover someone's rep ([example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PhloC.png))

Comment: The number format is different [even in the same page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193012/152859) sometimes.