# Prettify, commafy, beautify the question views

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, views

## A very small and rather simple suggestion...

Could you *please* (pretty please!) prettify the the number of times a question has been viewed, so that at a glance you can figure it out instead of having to ***decrypt*** it.

#### Current Look

[image]

I mean look at it! It isn't very user friendly.

#### Suggestion

Have it output as 296,877 instead of just 296877.

I thought I'd ask here so it could be implemented on all the sites network-wide.

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254346/add-separation-of-numbers-to-the-view-counter#comment830493_254346) (comment copied below) comment in this related question, I think anything just to split the numbers up would be better than the current system; spaces would be fine too.

> Commas should never happen due to internationalization concerns. The same goes with dots. The only "correct" option is following the ISO standard which calls for spaces. – psubsee2003 Apr 25 '15 at 21:02

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148048/should-the-network-use-thousands-separators-in-numbers

Comment: @PolyGeo I've seen a couple of questions like this on their respective meta sites, however the idea just seems to fade away.