# Add thousands separator to numbers in the Badges and Tags sections

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges

Can we add a thousands separator for large numbers on the badges and tags pages?

The current format doesn't use the commas:

[image: Badge]
would say `16,196`

Comment: Can you explain why you desire that?

Comment: I suspect simply because it's easy to read. Though I question the value of knowing whether there are 16,000 or 160,000 or 16 folks with that badge...

Comment: @Aaron The numbers are small enough that they're easy to read either way, aren't they?

Comment: Related: [Add thousands separators to the numbers of votes and edits displayed on the Users page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120971/add-thousands-separators-to-the-numbers-of-votes-and-edits-displayed-on-the-user)

Comment: @Daniel Depends on your eyesight (and, perhaps, state of inebriation) I suppose. I don't think the commas need to be there, but I can imagine how some folks may find it hard to read that number immediately.

Comment: Yes, to make them easier to read (and consistent with user's point counts). That particular number is not so hard to read, but the top tags on SO are harder.

Comment: It also makes sense, IMHO, to apply the same formatting to all numbers across the site.

Comment: @Aaron Could be. I guess I see a lot of numbers, so I'm used to it.

Comment: @DanielFischer I definitely find thousands separators easier to read. On 4 and 5 digit numbers it may not be all that valuable, but like I said - consistency is king.

Comment: @Aaron, yes, consistency is a good reason (although, a foolish consistency ...).

Comment: @Daniel I agree, but I'd love to hear arguments for keeping it inconsistent (aside from developer effort). :-)

Comment: It makes sense: The reputation does use the comma. I don't see why other numbers (which are probably more important) should not use it.

Comment: This becomes very important once over a million users have a certain bronze badge. 7 digit numbers are much more obviously 7 digits with the two thousands separators. This is still trivial priority though.

Answer (score 2):

We still don't have commas on the tag pages, but the badges page now uses a '*x.x*k' format:

> [image]

Though the people who have 1k+ of a single badge do still have the same issue:

> [image]

So I guess 1/3 of the issues have been fixed.