# Please format badge counts using thousands separators

Tags: feature-request

Before I start of, apologies if this isn't where I should put this, but I thought it would be a nice idea.

If you look on pages like https://stackoverflow.com/badges, you'll see stuff like

> Commentator × 220067

and, with PHP, you could *easily* add the English format...

```
 number_format(220067); // 220,067
```

I just thought it'd be a nice cosmetic change, because the current look is somewhat hard to read.

Comment: He refers to the inconsistency, whilst I refer the the page in specific.

Comment: You could write a userscript

Comment: You could also pick one of the duplicates he's referring to after the statement *"PLEASE NOTE: This is not a bug report about the individual cases where the use of thousands separators is inconsistent."*

Comment: For example [Add thousands separator to numbers in the Badges and Tags sections](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146992/add-thousands-separator-to-numbers-in-the-badges-and-tags-sections)

Comment: I'll probably write an application that does this for you, but I'd have to find the _dynamic_ values (e.g. if the site added a badge), so it's not something in my currently development range.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a jQuery plugin for this...

Comment: Is there an answered question that is talking directly about the badge counts? The only way it could be 'answered' is if a team member said 'no' or 'we did it,' which clearly isn't the case.

Comment: If you think your idea is a good one, make it a well motivated answer to the duplicate (if you're not repeating the other answers), or the other question I linked. We don't need multiple requests/discussions with the same idea.

Comment: @AdamRackis def not enough jquery in this question.