# Is "undownvote" really the right word?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

[image: Undownvote]

It seems like maybe cancelled downvote might be less...weird?

Comment: "Reverted downvote" should be the right term. Probably not enough space for it though.

Comment: Your right... it should be called "Removal of the downvote" for the sake of clarification :)

Comment: For some reason, even though I click upvote on this 1K+ times, only one vote registers...  *sigh*

Comment: Sure, for those [who've read 1984](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Newspeak_words#Preficies) ;-)

Comment: Me unupvoted? That's unpossible

Comment: @casperOne I hope you realize you just *unupvoted* .5k+ times

Comment: _no_ one can _not_ imagine anything that would _not_ be _not_ as bad as _undownvote_

Comment: Who is allowed to undownvote, only the original downvoter or anyone? Thankns.

Comment: I was just about to post a similar question on `unupvote` when I found this. I'm all for your suggestion.

Answer (score 15):

It's not really wrong, but I agree it's a bit weird.

It's even longer so it may not be practical, but I opt for

```
downvote removed
upvote removed
```

or

```
dv removed
uv removed
```

or as suggested by MDMarra

```
↓ removed
↑ removed
```

or as suggested by slhck, even more in keeping with SO's general design

```
▼ removed
▲ removed
```

?

Comment: I like it. Or even `↓ removed`

Comment: @MDMarra hey, that's cool!

Comment: Feel free to edit it into your answer. You inspired the idea with the dv abbreviation.

Comment: **"reverted" does not imply the same thing as "removed"**. A person can actively remove their vote, or a vote can passively be reverted by the system.

Comment: @slhck true ----

Comment: @slhck Can you please explain the difference? It seems like the two terms can be used interchangeably in either circumstance.

Comment: @MDMarra a downvote can be *reverted* by another user's upvote, while *removing* it definitely means the original downvote

Comment: @MDMarra I take removing as something you actively do as a user. For example, you downvote a post, it is improved, then you "remove" your downvote. In contrast, when talking about fraud votes, I mostly hear about "reverting" them, which isn't something *you* do, but the system does for you – as if they never existed.

Comment: @Pekka'sReputationBordello I wouldn't consider someone else upvoting a question to have *reverted* a different user's vote. Both votes are still present.

Comment: @slhck Personally, I don't see a distinction between the two. The system *removed* fraudulent votes. They were present at one point in time, and then they weren't.

Comment: @MDMarra You also have a point, but I've never heard someone say they *reverted* their own votes. Maybe this is getting too specific ;)

Comment: I still prefer "undownvote" over any of the short versions above.

Comment: @MDMarra and all, actually, the system thinks it [reverses vote fraud](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes/124217#124217).

Comment: "ex-downvote", eh?

Comment: If there is a distinction between a system action and a user action, I think withdrawn is good, as long as it only applies to the user action.

Comment: @MDMarra: I made my comment an answer.

Comment: If you use unicode arrows, that probably doesn't interact well with accessibility tools, like screen readers.

Comment: Do not want "dv removed", it's very unclear. upvote/downvote removed seem acceptable

Comment: @CodeInChaos How well do the current actual upvote/downvote arrows interact?

Comment: @MDMarra They consist of the text "up vote"/"down vote" styled with css to show arrows instead. The same method should be applied to this text, if icons are chosen, instead of just displaying a unicode character.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 15):

How about `downvote` to keep it both simple and within the space limits?

Comment: Even geniuser! +1. And show a "this downvote was removed by the user" tooltip

Comment: Yeah, I like this a lot.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a fan of the word "cast", so I recommend the following for when you vote up or down on a question:

- Vote up
- Vote down

If you want to replace that with iconography, that works too, but the above is pretty simple (even simpler than upvote/downvote, IMO) and should be understood by anyone looking at it.

However, I don't see the reason to use "removed", since the common terminology when it comes to votes is [*rescind*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rescind).

So I'd like to just see "rescind". I don't need to see "upvote/downvote".

IMO, "upvote"/"downvote" is an over-specialization of the voting action.  You simply cast a vote up or down, and conversely the action you perform is "rescind", the direction doesn't matter since its reflected in the rep.

You can even take it one step further and say that you can just have "Voted" when a user casts a vote, and let the rep reflect the direction the vote was cast.

If you want to be *really* consistent you can simply have:

- Vote cast
- Vote rescinded

Which ultimately, I like the best, as it reduces four states down to two while being consistent.

Comment: IMO rescind is a bit too fancy for a site with an international audience. I for one barely know it, and there surely are quite a few users with weaker English than me.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Perhaps, but remember, [English is the language of the Internet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow) at least from SO's point of view.  I guess the question is, what is the *minimum* amount of English that we require?

Comment: I have to agree that rescind is a bit of an overkill bordering on legalese.. (and in before the weaker-than-me vs weaker-than-I brigade)

Comment: Agree with 100% of this answer, except the part where you say you don't like "cast". Pray tell, why not?

Answer (score 4):

Compare:

```
cancelled downvote
undownvote
```

Granted, "undownvote" isn't a real word, but expanding it fully would amount to making the vote-type column much wider than it needs to be. "undownvote" keeps it still roughly in the same realm as when there are just normal votes.

Comment: I like MDMarra's idea: `↓ removed`

Comment: What about @Pekka's suggestion, or the use of the unicode down arrow? All of the currently supported browsers should be able to render it, right?

Comment: @MDMarra The arrow is never used anywhere else. If at all, it should be this: `▼`

Comment: I can get behind that.

Answer (score 4):

How about "withdrawn"? It sounds more of an active verb to me. Or would that be ambiguous as well?

> downvote withdrawn
>   upvote withdrawn

Comment: I like the word, but Grace made it clear that it's too long. Perhaps `▼ withdrawn`?

Comment: That looks good.

Answer (score 0):

The word undownvote implies that unupvote exists too.

I presume that is to differentiate it from [reversal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), which is what the system or devs do if you have serial voting occur. But the question: [Why are my downvotes being undownvoted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332643/why-are-my-downvotes-being-undownvoted) says that the system uses that word too.

Perhaps "reversed" would be appropriate if the system or a moderator reversed the decision and "reversal" ( or 180°, if eyesight/accessability is a concern) if the person changed their mind **after** five minutes. Made up words are probably challenging for some whom English is not their first language and they might feel excluded, not understanding the concept.

Comment: Yes, there also is [post_unupvoted](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/reputation-history)  see the `reputation_history_type` field