# Flurry of downvotes. Others too? Curious why

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

It almost looks as if [someone is playing police](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512728/jan-doggen?tab=reputation):

[image]

The downvotes are on:
[DCPCrypt/Delphi not properly encoding Rijndael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313992/dcpcrypt-delphi-not-properly-encoding-rijndael)
[SQL recursive records: How can I collapse to 'one level only'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727911/sql-recursive-records-how-can-i-collapse-to-one-level-only)
[Turbopower Lockbox3 - Can I control initialization vector and padding for AES-256 encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847759/turbopower-lockbox3-can-i-control-initialization-vector-and-padding-for-aes-25)
[Bi-weekly calendar appointment created through EWS showing up weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523556/bi-weekly-calendar-appointment-created-through-ews-showing-up-weird)
[How can I read the entire calendar user configuration in Exchange Web Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581721/how-can-i-read-the-entire-calendar-user-configuration-in-exchange-web-services)
[Drop indexes separately from drop table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397661/drop-indexes-separately-from-drop-table)
[Selecting top n Oracle records with ROWNUM still valid in subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489506/selecting-top-n-oracle-records-with-rownum-still-valid-in-subquery)
[Are PostMessage calls safe to a handle that's 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364187/are-postmessage-calls-safe-to-a-handle-thats-0)

If there's anything common among these downvoted questions it could be questions that I have not accepted and/or that were maybe were not good ideas to start with - but hey, that's part of why we ask questions ;-)

Has anyone else noticed this behaviour (at least one person has, see the undownvotes).
It does not look as if someone has taken offence at something I did, there would be more downvotes then.
I'm curious what can be going on, but I'm afraid there's not much I can find out at my level.

Comment: This doesn't look definitively suspicions, but there are scripts that find serial downvoting and reverse it. Also undownvotes are when the downvoter reverses their own vote

Comment: See [what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: @CodesInChaos That is usually called "Serial downvoting reversed"

Comment: _"at least one person has, see the undownvotes"_ -- based on what I see at your screen shot, that "person" is an automated script that runs at 3:00 GMT daily and invalidates suspicious votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Serial Voting

For assorted reasons people may start voting (either up or down) for a person rather than for content. If this has happened to you then automatic scripts run every night which reverse this; see [what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). In your case it's a bit close to call as to whether this definitely is serial voting. If they are all from the same user, the script will know and may reverse them (the exact algorithm is deliberately vague).

#### "Undownvote"

Undownvoted on the other hand simply means someone has removed their own downvote; perhaps you improved your post or they simply had a change of heart. See [is-undownvote-really-the-right-word](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124265/is-undownvote-really-the-right-word).

There may however be [a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198135/serial-downvote-reversals-dont-always-appear-as-such) in which serial downvote reversal is incorrectly marked as undownvote.

Comment: @Peter funnily I just made the same its vs it's correction to someone elses questions. Frankly the whole situation is ridiculous, I blame english

Comment: Blaming English is sensible, but blaming *the English* is much more fun.

Comment: Based on gnats comment (regarding time of undownvote) under the original post, it indeed looks like that +2+2+2 undownvotes may be a bug. Thanks all.