# Do we need the "authentification" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, burninate-request

Today I discovered a tag called [authentification](/questions/tagged/authentification). As far as I know, it is not an English word, but exists for example in French and must have been added by mistake. It currently has 35 questions.

I suggest we make it an synonym of [authentication](/questions/tagged/authentication) or burninate it.

Comment: It's authentication, [Jamaican style](http://www.speakjamaican.com/glossary/#f).

Comment: its an original Elliniki (greek) word coming from the `αυθέντης` [Ηρόδοτος Α117]. From this word coming the αφεντικό that means "the boss", that is the one that have the right to enter their account. "Authentication -> the permit to the boss of the account."

Comment: That's a pretty common problem for French people - "authentification" is the French term for this.

Comment: It's also the german term by the way...

Comment: I love that there is a *burninate-request* tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to make it a synonym.  At 32 questions, it doesn't have so many entries that it needs one.

Also, let's not forget that [English is the official language of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/140951), and that includes its tags.

Annnnd...  That tag is gone (I've also created a synonym from [auth](/questions/tagged/auth) to [authentication](/questions/tagged/authentication) in the process as well).

Unfortunately, there's still *this* problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=authentification

Comment: Wow. There's some.

Answer (score 0):

In two minds about this one.

- On the one hand, having it as a tag will potentially help French speakers searching for questions and answers.
- It is not an English word

On balance, I'd probably make it a synonym, as with 35 questions I guess the tag does get some use.

Comment: I have [proposed it as a synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/authentication/synonyms). Let's vote.

Comment: @bazmegakapa I've created the synonym for `auth`, but deleted the one for `authentification`; it's not an English word, and [English is the official language of Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/140951).