# What's happening with traducir.win?

Tags: bug, traducir

Currently for [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/) I got the following:

> [image]

Is it a part of [migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388400/339911) to the SO ownership? Or some kind of erroneous behavior?

Outage is not mentioned on the suggested duplicate as noted in the comment below.

Comment: Moving to leave open. The author is aware of the other post, as is indicated in the final paragraph. Nowhere is it mentioned that there will be an outage in the other post.

Comment: Unable to reproduce now.

Comment: It's being moved. Totally expected to get lots of downtimes during something like that. (Moved from the one who created it and hosting it on their own devices, to SE servers, as far as I know)

Comment: I think it makes sense to close it as a duplicate of the other post; the answer's just that a tiny bit of downtime was expected during the migration, and it seems to have been resolved once the migration was finished. Now that the initial migration is done (AFAIK), if there are any issues going forward, they can be reported separately.