# No sync among Traducir and Transifex

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, transifex, traducir

It seems that after [migration Traducir into SO internal resources](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388400/339911) we lost translation synchronization.

In particular translations were made several days ago in Traducir still don't reach Transifex and hence not visible on the site despite several site's builds after that.

I made a new translation directly on Transifex and now (on the recent new build) it's live on site. So there's obviously broken chain somewhere in the middle between Traducir - Transifex.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow up and see what I can find out about this.

Comment: Hi @αλεχολυτ!  We've identified the issue with Traducir and are currently working on a fix.  Will update as soon as we've got more information.

Comment: @PeterO'Connor looks like the fix in production already?

Comment: Hello @αλεχολυτ!  Yes, we were able to resolve the issues with Traducir pushing out new translations.  I'm glad you're already seeing them!