# Recently added translations don't reach the site

Tags: bug, localization, transifex, traducir

Several builds ago I made a couple new translations via traducir.win, all these translations are visible on transifex. So the issue is different from the last one: [No sync among Traducir and Transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388888/339911). But for some reason they didn't reach the site UI.

Translations were made on 2023.8.24.**43599** build, current build is 2023.9.5.**43611**.

Is there all good with translation workflow?

Comment: Well the builds don't mean much, as far as I know, developer has to merge/push the changes to production first, and looks like this is the missing part.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard AFAIK every new build should rely on the latest translation state taken from Transifex. If there's update on Transifex side prior new build that data (in normal case) will be delivered to the site.

Comment: You mean the translations don't go through developer review or approval?

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard exactly. The quality of translations on the regular user's side (who has a Reviewer role on Traducir) per each non-English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks fixed on 2023.9.6.**43614**. I see the recently added translations.

Thanks to all involved.