# What's the exact data flow for translations on non-English sites?

Tags: support, localization, transifex, traducir

> This question was originally posted on [ModTeam](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/moderators/q/5143/825), but I decided that it would be better to post it here on open space, since not only mods/staff can participate on SE sites localization process.

To add or update translations on non-English language sites of SE (e.g. Stack Overflow in Russian/Spanish/Portuguese/Japanese), now we use traducir.win (it has been [recently migrated to the company ownership](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388400/339911)). As far as I know, after the translation was done on Traducir, it goes to Transifex and finally any following site's build (revision number on the bottom of each page) pull the translations from Transifex and the end user will see the result on site.

But as I noticed that **not every new build brings us the new translation** even when it's done on Traducir side. Hence I have a question: How I can be sure that the translation will come to the site, what number of builds are needed, and in general what's the exact workflow for updating the translations on non-English sites?

Related question: [Recently added translations don't reach the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392651/339911)