# Recently added translations don't reach the site again

Tags: bug, status-review, localization, transifex, traducir

Three months ago we had the similar problem: [Recently added translations don't reach the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392651/339911) that was resolved during the week without any visible feedback from the staff.

Now the issue arise again. I did some translations about 2 weeks ago, they are visible on Transifex side, but for some reason don't reach the site itself. There were several site's builds since that.

Comment: In the Japanese version of Stack Overflow, the translation was reflected in `rev 2023.12.8.2394`.
Thank you to everyone who responded to this issue.

(Please note that this issue poses great difficulties to translation work.
This has been happening frequently for over a year.
I hope this is the last time. )

Comment: Oh, it looks like there's still a problem.
It seems that a slightly older translation file is being reflected.
If the problem persists, I'll report back.

Comment: @mjy the problem still persists on ruSO. I made new translations, waited for new builds, but site still has old untranslated sentences.

Comment: The situation is uncertain and translation remains difficult.
Depending on the build, the translation may progress or not at all.

Currently, the Japanese version seems to reflect the translation until around 2023-12-13. In any case, translations are not keeping up with the latest ones these days.