# Overlapped items on cookie customization popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, cookies, cookie-consent-dialog

There are overlapping items on cookie customization popup on mobile devices like Android phone:

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[UPDATE] Issue resolved.**

Thanks for the report. The team is aware and working on the issue. I'll update this answer when this has been resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please try to escalate another one, but from my point of view more important [issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395096/339911). Non-English sites are struggling of translations lack until it will be fixed.

Comment: Translation issues are ["fixed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396660/339911) for this part is even better, than I was expecting :)