# Cookie notice popup is in Russian even for English sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, cookie-consent-dialog

For instance even on https://stackoverflow.com/ (just open it in browser private mode) I see cookie notice popup in Russian:

> [image]

Possibly related to this [Overlapped items on cookie customization popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396545/339911)

Comment: This smells more like it might be a feature (of the 3rd party cookie consent solution) than a bug. **If** your browser is sending an `Accept-Language` header which suggests your preferred language is `ru-RU` (IIRC you're a mod on ru.stackoverflow.com so that's well within the realms of possibility) then it's quite reasonable for something to present you with a Russian UI, if it can

Comment: @Rob good point, but I also noticed that such cookie notices are different for different geographical areas. [Post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13176/176217) on ruSO.meta for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the report. You should see the correct language now.

---

**[UPDATE Mar 11]** Changed this back to [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review). Will update once resolved.

---

**[UPDATE Mar 12]** Issue confirmed resolved.

Comment: [It is very funny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvKCi.jpg). Looks like this fix isn't easy.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Did you try clearing your browser's cache before taking that screenshot?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog no. Is it needed? Because on enSO problem is fixed for me. But it appears on MSE. Update: even on enSO I see cookie notice in Russian.

Comment: What's the "Correct" language, then? The site's language, or the language the browser is requesting using `Accept-Language` headers? I would argue that displaying the popup in the language the browser requests would be preferable, as that's apparently the language the user is most comfortable with.

Comment: @Cerbrus doesn't matter, the answer is wrong and misleading.

Comment: No, @ShadowWizardLoveZelda it _does_ matter. If "Correct language" is browser language, then the answer is correct...

Comment: @Dalmarus, can you please clarify?

Comment: @Cerbrus The language seen in the cookies should be whichever language you have that particular Stack site set for. If the issue is still persisting, try clearing the browser cache and check again (or open an incognito tab and try). If it's still occurring after that, let me know and I'll have the team look into it further.

Comment: @Dalmarus Thanks for the clarification. I can't reproduce this, as I only use English...

Comment: @Dalmarus I'm still seeing it in Russian in incognito mode on enSO. [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meFhX.png)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Thanks. I've re-opened the issue with the team and will update the answer and tags here again once I have more info.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ When you get a chance, let me know if you're still seeing it. Should be fixed now, but I'll wait a couple days to resolve this unless I hear back. Thanks again for flagging!

Comment: It looks good now, English on enSO, Russian on ruSO, Portuguese on ptSO etc. Thanks for fixing.

Comment: Great! Thanks for checking.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ you forgot [jaSO](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/). ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda it's covered by "etc" as well as esSO.