# Prevent browser popup error on wrong regex in Traducir

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, localization, user-experience, traducir

Since [traducir.win is now under SO responsibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388400/339911), could you please prevent the browser popup error from appearing on wrong regex input, and showing it again and again if I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close that popup? See the GIF below for clarity:

> [image]

Closing the popup via <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, or pressing the "Ok" button stops the loop. But in general it would be better to not raise the popup at all, because I don't want to spend time closing it while typing the query.

Moving the notice to somewhere else on the page itself, maybe next to the results, would be a more suitable solution.

You can test the behavior yourself [here](https://ru.traducir.win/).

Comment: That is ... pretty annoying

Comment: It is definitely a very annoying behaviour. I made a quick fix to prevent the popup (it was the existing behaviour) and it will be deployed soon.

Comment: It is now fixed.

Comment: @onatm I see. Thanks! Please set [status-completed] on the current Q.

Comment: @onatm but is it showing anywhere now if the regex is wrong? If not, should we start a new feature request asking to add such a feature? (In some better way than popup. ;))