# Very high reputation for post on reputation tab of profile

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

Just looked on my [reputation in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84?tab=reputation&StartDate=2023-05-18%2011:01:20Z&sort=time) and got the following:

> [image]

What's the amount of reputation is displayed next the my recent post?

Links to that post:

- [Prevent browser popup error on wrong regex in Traducir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389258/339911)

Comment: please also use words and not just images to convey this info. ex. the fact that the number is greater than 200 (which is surprising, given the rep cap)

Comment: This has been happening since the "recent" redesign of the profile pages. It's been reported many times on both MSE and MSO (and probably elsewhere), but SE hasn't fixed it.