# Did I reach the reputation cap or not?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

There was a couple of issues I faced recently with reputation on this site:

- [Very high reputation for post on reputation tab of profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389271/339911)
- [Different reputation on GUI and via the text reputation page. How many reputation points have I got?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389276/339911)

All that I got there was I [can't make any assumptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389276/different-reputation-on-gui-and-via-the-text-reputation-page-how-many-reputatio#comment1298139_389276) based on the `/reputation` text-based page. And that [the time tab on reputation page is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377620/339911).

Thus I'm curious how can I check did I actually reach reputation cap on May 18 or didn't. Did that day increase the counter for  [Epic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/epic) and [Legendary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary) badges?

In total I have `(13+10+3+1) = 27` upvotes, `1` downvote and `1` record of "Voting corrected" (`-10rep`) on May 18. A simple sum gives me `27*10 - 1*10 - 1*10 = 250` rep points. On the reputation page I see the value `190`. On the text-based page `200`. Where's the right amount I've earned and why?

Comment: Perhaps this: You reached the reputation cap, and the final voting correction dropped you back to 190 from 200.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you did. I've said this before, but to repeat: the total displayed for the day has absolutely nothing to do with the reputation cap. If you have additional votes counting for 0 on the day, it's because you hit the cap.

The total for each day is your *net change* of all events that occurred that day. Some events, like "user was removed" and "voting corrected" events can reverse events from previous days. For record-keeping, the deduction is displayed for that day even though it does not affect the reputation cap for the day and you can't compensate it with additional upvotes that day. Though, if you hit the reputation cap on the original days those votes occurred, other votes on those days will be retroactively recalculated to gain reputation to compensate for the ones that are now reversed.

Also of note: the Epic and Legendary badges have nothing to do with the reputation cap either. They are awarded for earning a total of 200 reputation on a number of days. And those days ignore any losses too (even downvotes). So as long as you *earned* 200 that day, the day counts towards the badges. You can earn 250 reputation and then get downvoted into oblivion where the day nets you 0 reputation, and the day would still count.

While the `/reputation` page is by no means guaranteed to be accurate, it *should be* pretty close if not. It's just displaying the information in a completely different way than the profile does (it's raw data, and doesn't include deleted votes at all). That page doesn't do anything special and is designed to not need maintenance on our part. It just grabs your full reputation breakdown, the same breakdown that is used to do a rep recalc, and then throws it into a sort of StringBuilder that converts all the data into lines of text. People saying it's "not maintained" is a bit inaccurate because there's not really anything to maintain. As we change how reputation works, that page Just Works because it pulls from the same source.