# Add link to filter by key for pluralizable strings in Traducir

Tags: feature-request, localization, plurals, traducir

> Please read this post before: [We’re moving Traducir to our internal infrastructure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388400/339911)

Each string in Traducir has a link to its Transifex source. In case of pluralizable strings, this link contains a direct link to the specific string variant, [e.g.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/8925):

> [image]

It would be better to include the link (in Traducir basis) to the root strings by key (without variant at path) to display all variants at once, i.e.:

> https://ru.traducir.win/filters?key=e70c5853db6a66e7d283706826de113c

This will help us to make consistent translations for different variants (plural forms). Currently I need to copy the source or key root part and filter the result by hand, and it is slightly tedious.

Could that link please be added to mentioned above popup window?