# Prevent losing uncommitted translation input on popup editor close in Traducir

Tags: feature-request, localization, user-experience, traducir

> Context on Stack's community translation platform moving to be internally hosted:
> [We’re moving Traducir to our internal infrastructure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388400/339911)

Editing the translation in Traducir takes place in a popup window. If you occasionally click outside the popup, it will close, and any unsaved translation typed into the popup will be lost, [e.g.](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=vote):

> [image: Unsaved text in the editor popup is cleared and lost if the user accidentally clicks outside the popup and closes it]

Could we somehow prevent the loss of user input in such cases? Possible options may include, but are not limited to:

- Ask for confirmation when closing if there is some unsaved translation
- Store the last-made uncommitted translation somewhere in cache, so that it can be restored on the following popup open.

Comment: Another lesser option is to prevent closing the modal on anything except for clicking the "X" in the top right. It looks like a bootstrap modal and I think there is a setting for that.