# Preserve entered values on traducir after login

Tags: feature-request, login, traducir

Reminder: [We’re moving Traducir to our internal infrastructure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388400/339911)

Occasionally, I lose my login session on traducir.win and have to login again. This is not a complicated task, but it's hard to notice whether I am logged in or not, prior to filling in some input fields. For instance, I've entered a "too long" string to filter the results, and after that made a login. All my entered data has cleared and I have to type it again:

> [image: Traducir data form resets when logging in]

Could we please preserve the data entered before login on after the login stage?