# How can I find previous (but currently outdated) translation made by any user in Traducir?

Tags: support, localization, traducir

Reminder: [We’re moving Traducir to our internal infrastructure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388400/339911)

When the original string is changed then the whole translation that was made for that string before is gone from the site's user interface. It's not a problem for completely removed strings, but an issue if the source string is just slightly modified. In that case it would be great to somehow find the old translation, make a correction and submit it again.

Every (I hope) Traducir user has an ability to list all their recently made translation via the link, e.g. for ruSO: [https://ru.traducir.win/users/{user_id}/suggestions](https://ru.traducir.win/users/%7Buser_id%7D/suggestions). So it's possible to look up on own last translations by searching through the page via Ctrl+F. But is there a way to find all previous translations to make (or suggest) a new tune-in translation for slightly modified string?

Comment: Since every string is treated different, Traducir doesn't look up for another one. You have no way to know wich string this one has changed from. transifex doesn't give a hint about it, and the code doesn't have it either. Usually, when things like this happens, CM used to let us know what was changed, to look up similar strings. You can search the text in textbox, if you know the original one...

Comment: Users with rol reviewer can see the translations made by any other user...

Comment: @gbianchi unfortunately we don't have CM on ruSO anymore. I'm looking for the way where I can take old (but outdated) translation and adapt it for new source, because it's easier than translate it again and again, if just the minor part of source string is changed.

Comment: I think neither of has a unique CM ;)... what if you look up on the source regexp? if you have similar keywords, you can try them...

Comment: @gbianchi I wanted to find lost TRANSLATION, not a similar SOURCE. The needed translation I've already found in my own suggestions page, but I'm looking how I can resolve common case in future, i.e. when translation was made by someone else.

Comment: when you say lost translations, you mean a translation that is not anymore on transifex? I think I'm missing something here... let ask about it to Gervasio... I will try to summon him here...

Comment: Using database backups is an option if you want to dig old Traducir data. But i think the current model in Traducir is that old strings are deleted after some period, and translations for them too.

Comment: Actually i was wrong, it does not delete strings, only sets deletion date: https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/blob/master/Traducir.Core/Services/SOStringService.cs#L130 So it should be totally possible to query old deleted strings on database from backups.

Comment: This is something I've asked about internally as well. It's apparently possible to query/look through Traducir's database backups using SQL Server (though I've never used SQL Server myself). It's currently not possible to query/retrieve those translations in Traducir directly, but I have submitted a feature request for that.