# Users who are not moderators anymore still have diamond next to their names on Traducir

Tags: bug, moderators, traducir

Reminder: [We’re moving Traducir to our internal infrastructure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388400/339911)

On [traducir users page](https://ru.traducir.win/users/) several users still have a moderator's diamond.

> [image]

They don't have moderator abilities on the site anymore. Moreover PashaPash even has deleted his profile on the ruSO. You can check it by following the links from mentioned page.

Additional interesting moment that all these users have "Reviewer" role, that they got within diamond, but didn't lost after stepping down on the site.

Comment: First part is valid bug. Second is questionable, it was not stated anywhere that stepping down as moderator should automatically remove reviewer status on Traducir.

Comment: To be honest, not sure what's the actual use of the users page. It just links to the actual profile on SE, and serve no real purpose as far as I can see. If there will be stats, badges, etc, then maybe it will be nice to have, but as it stands now, I'd support having it removed as it's obviously not synched with the actual users. Do note, SEDE also has users page, however all the users are part of SEDE itself, it's not link only to the SE profiles.

Comment: Side question, was g3rv4 ever been a mod?

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard he used to work in company

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight it should depend on how the role was acquired. If they got it due to being a mod, then it should be retracted. E.g. mod signed on Traducir and get Reviewer role (no other action needed), other mod didn't sign on Traducir. Both stepped down. In latter case ex-mod won't be a Reviewer after signing on, but the first one ex-mod will. It's illogical.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard the purpose of this page is to make additional actions available by clicking on color (blue, yellow, red) buttons and viewing the user role on Traducir.

Comment: @Pet  as far as I know/remember, g3r built it from scratch as a side project, to help/automate translations, all while working in SE as developer, but it was never official project. Until SE saw it's good, so when he left the company, they asked him to pass it over.

Comment: Weirdly, my own diamond is now gone on Traducir (though I still have the Reviewer role), but other ex-staff still have theirs. (I wonder if it has do with whether they've logged in since losing the diamond?)