# Internal error on traducir.win

Tags: bug, traducir

> Reminder: [We’re moving Traducir to our internal infrastructure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388400/we-re-moving-traducir-to-our-internal-infrastructure)

Today I faced several times with an internal error on ru.traducir.win like this:

> [image]

Other times site works significantly slower than before.

Comment: Yup, can repro. The same issue happens on other Traducir, e.g. https://ja.traducir.win

Comment: Only happens on the UserService? Full exception message: `Database 'ja-db' on server 'sql-nqm4.database.windows.net' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection later.  If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of '{70200245-54BF-40AD-BA3F-DD87F81A881D}'.`

Comment: Here is a mini-profiler log for a successful  call but took a long time to complete: https://ru.traducir.win/mini-profiler-resources/results?id=1a6d6b15-08ac-4a76-acd9-e537ef2aba3a

Comment: Almost certainly due to [this incident involving Azure SQL Database](https://azure.status.microsoft/en-us/status/history/#:~:text=Tracking%20ID%3A%202LZ0).