# Are questions on the stackexchange site strictly english?

Tags: discussion, languages

I am wondering if sites on the stackexchange are strictly english in the sense that if I wanted to post a question in an other language in stackoverflow, would it be closed for not being in English?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Are you asking primarily about Stack Overflow, or Stack Exchange sites in general?

Comment: Note that the question about "Stack Exchange" might have a different answer than for "Stack Overflow". The linked-to question is *mostly* about SO (and the trilogy).

Comment: lol this sentence makes my blood coagulate: "English is as close that we have ever come to a global lingua-franca."  But the point is taken/understood.

Comment: There are a couple of stack-exchange sites(typically related to that language) where other languages are OK. But for most sites, English it is.

Answer (score -2):

I have not found anything that strictly says that SO is limited to questions in the english language, although any questions and answers in other languages are often closed quickly (for various reasons)

Comment: One reason is that we don't understand them. :-)

Comment: That does not mean that it does not belong. It is not your fault (or thiers) that you speak different languages.

Comment: The linked dupe (from the FAQ) says exactly that, Grammer.

Comment: @BoPersson I'm curious because if you don't understand a question because of the language used and you don't understand a question because their English level is too low... Then basically if you don't have even a basic understanding of English, you are not going to come here.

Comment: In my opinion, if they are concerned enough to come to SO, even if they can't speak english, then they deserve a shot at an answer, even if it uses google translate for english -> other language translations