# Asking/Answering questions in a language other than English

Tags: support, languages

What is the SO policy about asking and/or answering questions in languages other than English?

Comment: It depends. If that other language is C++, Java, PHP, Javascript, etc... then you're fine.

Comment: It's "Don't ask and/or answer questions in a language other than English."

Comment: @DavidRobinson I thought that was the case. Just wanted confirmation.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @Mysticial Attempting to post a question all in C++ will get an error, from what I understand.