# Flag comment not in English

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, non-english-speakers, english

Should comments that are not in English be flagged? What if the OP understands an answer in some other language, and not in English: should such posts still be flagged?

Comment: I would leave one comment aimed at specific user if it's non English. When it becomes a discussion I'll flag and want to see it all cleaned up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Stack Overflow is English only.

And here's where it's out as official policy: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: 唉，那次论据实在以不受控制了！

Comment: 我同意！ -----------

Comment: 我敢打赌，你看着这个在谷歌翻译

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Merci! Gracias! (About the comment thread...)

Comment: 帝国主义的走狗走出越南。 -----------

Comment: @Bart 不，我没有。这是离谱的。

Comment: This is making me dizzy... Do all of you speak fluent Japanese/Chinese, or is Google Translate just having a good day?

Comment: אני לא אומר. So there.

Comment: @Linuxios: I'm a native Chinese speaker. I can't speak (ha!) for the rest, though...

Comment: Any foreign language is Greek to me anyway.....

Comment: And this is why we use English...

Comment: English is foreign to me?

Comment: Dwy i ddim yn deall. Cymraeg am byth!

Comment: 敏捷的棕色狐狸跃过那只懒狗 。