# Asking and answering questions in Spanish

Tags: discussion, languages, non-english-speakers, english

I am from Venezuela and I do not speak English. I would like to help out here however, to answer questions I need to use Google Translate.

May I ask (and answer) questions in Spanish?

Comment: I think there is a proposal for a spanish SO on [area51.se]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 14):

No you are not allowed.

Stack Overflow is an English only website.

You *can* support the [Stack Overflow in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) suggestion on area51, however.

Comment: Work on the Spanish StackOverflow site will begin on August 1, 2015 with a launch date of late October-early November of 2015.  You will be able to ask **and** answer questions in Spanish there.

Comment: @JuanM : Your comment is obsolete from a while :P ¡Abrazos!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. Stack Overflow is an English only site.

I'd recommend you do your best to translate the question to English, (you've done a reasonably good job here), and post it. Small grammatical mistakes will usually be corrected by the community fairly quickly. Of course, be sure to respond to requests for clarification to the best of your ability as well, in the event that something is lost in the translation.