# How should I flag an answer in Spanish?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, new-users

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19452803/931721) when reviewing first posts. It answers the question, but it's in Spanish. How should I flag it?

- It's not spam
- It's not offensive, abusive, or hate speech
- It is an answer
- I don't think it fits as "very low quality" since it suggests a good solution
- Other (needs ♦ moderator attention)?

Comment: Are you able to translate it fairly accurately?

Comment: I think I can translate most of it.

Comment: con una bandera

Comment: @chris hahahaha

Answer (score 9):

If it looks like an answer (and not a follow-on question or a "me too" comment), but is simply written in another language, I might not flag these right away. What I'd do is leave a comment explaining that Stack Exchange sites are (for the time being) [English-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow), and that we'd greatly appreciate it if they'd reword their answer in English. Even better, if you were familiar with the language in question, edit the answer to translate it.

This at least explains to the answerer why there's a problem with their answer, and gives them a chance to correct it. I'd like to give them that opportunity, since they might not know about the English-only policy here.

If they don't respond to the comment in a timely manner, that's when I'd flag the answer with a custom flag explaining that they were asked to translate a non-English answer, but haven't. I have no problem with removing an answer at that point.

Comment: The person answering that question has an unregistered account, is answering in a foreign language, and is answering a question that was already answered adequately *with the same information* 3 years ago.  Nuking is the preferred option here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Yes, in this case, I agree. For others that leave non-English answers that might add something new to the question, I'd like to give them a chance to correct that. That might just be me being a bleeding heart, though.

Comment: @BradLarson At the same time it encourages people to just keep posting answers in their own language hoping/expecting that someone else will just translate it.

Comment: Please add a link to the English-only policy statement.

Comment: @hus787 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684

Comment: Even though I've said "help translate if possible in the past", I see why this can be a problem.  But I am in favor of the rest of this answer since it puts the onus on the poster to fix it just like any other marginal quality post.  However, if you are able to read the language and see it offers nothing, then flag away

Answer (score 8):

Flag it using a custom flag, and put "Not in English" in the flag explanation.

Worth noting: the question is more than three years old, and the Spanish answer (just posted by an unregistered user) merely repeats the information in the top-voted answer.

Questions and answers posted in a foreign language are the moral equivalent of graffiti.  Treat them accordingly.