# How to ask - language info

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, asking-questions, languages

On a few occasions I have come across a question that is written in French. I understand such situation is not a common problem but it happens from time to time. My suggestion is to add short information that questions should only be asked in English at **How to ask** section.

[image: screenshot of 'how to ask']

The problem isn't very big, but the solution may be as short. Additionally I haven't anywhere seen information that tells users to only use English.

Comment: Hm, isn't the fact the whole site (including the "how to ask" guidelines) is in English enough to convey the message that we expect all posts to be written in English?

Comment: There is a place on Meta: [Is English required on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/168333). But we can't expect a new member to find that without looking.

Comment: @Yannis Eso no es una suposición razonable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is *tons* and *tons* of possibly helpful information that could be included in the How to Ask page.  You could write an entire book about how to ask a good question.  We simply can't include *that* much information on the page, as this site uses it, because if we did nobody would read it.  We need to trim it down to just the bare essentials; the most important aspects of information that we want to convey to people asking a question here.

People posting questions in another language simply *isn't* enough of a problem to warrant bringing it up in the How to Ask.  *Most* of the people reading it won't benefit from hearing that.

On top of it simply not being *that* big of a problem, most of the people who *do* post questions in other languages aren't reading "how to ask", or wouldn't be understanding most of it due to a lack of understanding of English.  The number of people this would actually help would be *very* small.

Comment: Agreed on all counts.