# How to deal with [faq] questions whose top answer is obsolete but is a useful opinion piece?

Tags: discussion, meta, etiquette, mso-mse-split

Consider a question like [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). It has the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag. Its top answer is for the most part an opinion piece.

This opinion piece is solely about Stack Overflow; it no longer applies now that the question has been moved to Meta Stack Exchange. It would do fine on Meta Stack Overflow.

What should we do? Some possibilities:

- Migrate the thread back to MSO – that's what I favor, but it was denied (and the question got a cosmetic edit changing “Stack Overflow” to “Stack Exchange” – which means that now none of the answers address the question).
- Post a new answer and declare it to be “the” answer. Easy, but insufficient: the top answer is what most visitors will see – the top answer should be the one that actually answers the question.
- Delete all the obsolete answers. But why would we delete a debate about SO? It's a perfectly legitimate debate, just out of place now.
- Edit the top answer. I'd have no problem with that if it was an obsolete statement of fact, but it's a still-relevant opinion piece.

Comment: That was always my least favorite FAQ just because of how opinionated and unofficial all the information was. I did try to tidy it up (there are a lot of deleted answers there) a little bit when I was on my FAQ clean-up campaign, but that's just... Ugh...

Comment: @animuson It kind of made sense as an SO FAQ — the choice to keep SO in English was a community consensus. (It was also a decision from above, but the fact that it was a community consensus reinforced it.) But now on MSE it doesn't work (random trolls notwithstanding). Still, as a general principle, I agree that [tag:faq] questions should be written as such, it's rarely a good idea to repurpose an existing discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem with that answer. It starts by stating a trilogy policy (it would be trivial to edit it to say Stack Exchange instead) and then carefully supports the policy with still-relevant opinion. I don't see that it's completely about SO at all. Why do you want to replace it? And what would you replace it with? I would support leaving it as it is or very lightly editing it to reflect current reality, including that not all the sites are programming sites (not removing the thing about most programming languages being in English, but just adding a caveat like *on our programming-related sites, there is also the consideration that most programming languages are in English* to lead off that paragraph.

Comment: The opinion part is about a programmers' site. It doesn't apply to a site about, say, cooking. Only the leading paragraph is obsolete information, the rest is not obsolete but does not answer the revised question.

Comment: I don't see that. The chart of languages spoken, for example, comes from Wikipedia, not some survey of SO users. Only the paragraph about programming languages is specific to SO (and the other programmingy sites) and it's a trivial edit to soften that point a little.

Comment: If we are going to tidy up that answer to make it more official and/or generic, would it also be right to remove the references the author makes to himself in a few of the sentences?

Comment: @slugster If we tidy up that answer, all the references to the original author would have to go.