# Are there Stack Exchanges in different languages?

Tags: support, area-51, languages, localization

I was wondering if there was, say, a "Spanish Stack Overflow." This would be the same as the Stack Overflow site, but people would ask and answer in *Spanish*. This way, the asker doesn't need a translator or knowledge of a foreign language to ask a question of the Stack Exchange community. Does something like this exist already, or could it be proposed in Area 51?

Note: This is ***NOT*** like Spanish Language Stack Exchange; questions there are about Spanish, but in English rather than about other topics, in Spanish.

Comment: There are several different language versions of Stack Overflow, specifically, now. Search "Stack Overflow" in the site selector on the top bar and you'll see (at least some of) them.

Comment: All of the sites in the Stack Exchange network are listed at http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see these. I don't actually use Stack Overflow in particular, that was just an example. Sorry.

Comment: The end of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/230261 already has the requested list and all related info, and it's kept up to date by the community, so not too sure about the wisdom of reopen votes or the loss of a good search signpost. It is probably a good idea to look further than titles when working through the review queue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We do indeed have [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), for Spanish-language speakers. The same is true for [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), and [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/). A [Stack Overflow in Turkish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-Turkish) has reached the commitment stage, and <strike>will enter beta at some point in the future</strike> has now been removed; new non-English sites will not be opening for some time.

[Many others](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1235/can-a-stack-overflow-proposal-in-a-different-language-be-called-xx-stackoverflow) have been proposed; lots have been closed. You do need a big enough community to make the sites work. In some cases, there isn't quite enough support. See also [this question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/are-stack-overflow-in-language-x-proposals-actually-viable?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Additionally, I seem to recall a Community Manager saying that before a [Topic X] in [Language Y] site can begin, there must already be a [Stack Overflow in Language Y] site up, running, and healthy. But I can't give you a source for that.

Comment: I wouldn't say the Turkish SO will launch at any point in the *near* future. Just at some point in the future. We are currently not opening *any* new sites in other languages until further notice.

Comment: @animuson Okay, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @HDE226868 what happened to Stack Overflow in Turkish? :)

Comment: it would be nice to comment on the reasoning of why "new non-English sites will not be opening for some time". If it is because there's not enough interest for nay other language to make this practical, it is a bit sad, but understandable. But this answer can also be interpreted as "We believe English, Portuguese, Russian, and Japanese to be better than other languages. Until someone proves us otherwise, people who do not speak these languages should learn a real language". I believe it's the former, but being explicit and truthful would be nice.