# How long to wait until close-voting a non-English post on an English site

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

The canonical FAQ *[Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)* tells us to

> vote or flag to close it (*the post*)

<sup>*emphasis mine*</sup>

Often curating users write a comment and ask to translate the OP (original post). Should we wait for a short while (maybe 30 minutes) for a reaction to the comment before taking above actions (specially when you understand the foreign language and see a OK post in the making? Or should we downvote and close-vote right away and eventually, if the post was translated and turns out a good post, vote to reopen it?

Comment: From years of experience, no it's pointless to wait. They never respond, they most likely never even read, so it's just waste of time.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/1038015

Comment: Slightly related: *[Is there a recent change of the way on how we flag non-English content with low quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422474/is-there-a-recent-change-of-the-way-on-how-we-flag-non-english-content-with-low)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no harm in voting to close right away, especially not if you follow the question and retract the vote when appropriate. In my experience, the success rate of those comments is less than 50%, and you've already indicated it can be reopened if it's closed while the author is still busy fixing the question.

Note that the FAQ doesn't talk about *down*voting, so you might indeed not want to do that if you see an OK post in the making. The author sees the question score (but not the close votes) and might get demotivated from the downvotes.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really think downvoting is necessary. I like a good downvote and I don't advocate for getting rid of them but I do sometimes feel like they get used more than they deserve.

Comment: not downvoting, at least not right away, is a good point here! thanks

Comment: Difficult to argue that a question written in a language that cannot be read by the majority of the site's users, not to mention is explicitly forbidden, fails to meet the standard of "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Answer (score 5):

None. No waiting. Just like for every other post that is not suitable in its current state, the question should be closed until it meets the standard required.

No need to worry whether an answer is based on a mistranslation, or whether others will be able to use the Q&A pair in future given the necessary bilingualism.

If the edit happens soon, great, it can be reopened. If the edit never happens, great, it will be cleaned up later. There is no need for any special thought or process simply because the problem is "post not in English".