# Why not translate posts by community?

Tags: discussion, area-51, languages, non-english-speakers

At area51 are multiple proposals for sites that already exists, only in another language. Actually I've committed for the German unit of Stackoverflow.
And that just because I want to provide some of the already collected knowledge to those that cannot speak English.

I'm aware that the automatic translation today will not gain the quality we're all striving for.
But I think the sites would gain more quality if the users are able to translate every single post into English or their native language.

So I will explain my vision:
The main language will be English, but everyone can post in native.
The posts will drive a new queue where reviewers just have to decide if there is a translation into English needed.
Answers in English have to pass a queue which only native speakers can review and translate it from English.
If a post is available in another language than English, there will be an option to show it.

No matter how many non-English speakers would post questions in their native language, "normal" users will not be disturbed by post they cannot read.
Nonetheless more users could participate, so it would help to grow the community and improve the quality, because forcing someone to use a specific language will reduce the amount of good questions. 
Further the time to get an answer in cause of the queue-passing will encourage the users to post in English.
Rewarding users for approved translations will boost the range of people which could gain knowledge.

---

After posting this, I've found the results in the related link list which I've searched for before, so myself flagged this one as duplicate...

More links:

- [Why don't they just make SO multilingual? It's possible!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/why-dont-they-just-make-so-multilingual-its-possible?rq=1)
- [Should we do anything about the huge language mess on Area51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79712/should-we-do-anything-about-the-huge-language-mess-on-area51?rq=1)
- [Non-English Q&A translations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171034/non-english-qa-translations?rq=1)

Comment: It doesn't scale. Also, comments to clarify problematic posts *really* don't scale. Picture the Spanish post translated to English, translated to German, where someone asks a clarifying comment in German - getting that back to the OP... Or an answer posted in German that no one translates to English (or Spanish) for a month or two for the OP to evaluate.. Oh, the 'fun' of it all.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right... I've just focused at the posts itself, while forgetting that there is much more interaction that has to be translated... If you post this as an answer, I will accept it resignedly :/

Comment: [There is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264688/an-alternative-to-creating-language-specific-sites) a less radical proposal, focused on intermediate-level knowledge of English augmented with some another language of greater fluency.

Answer (score 1):

A new que would take a lot of time from people. Also, these new sites exist because of other reasons. On Stack Exchange especially, the code wouldn't be translated right in many cases. Take this for example
`var t = "some words"` translated to Spanish = `var t = "somewords"`. The sites *are* necessary, and you pretty much say so yourself.

Comment: The sample you've provided is irrelevant, because its a String and should not have to be translated to solve a technical problem...

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach `var` at a very minimum would need to be translated for the program to work.

Comment: ? `var` is `var`, just the value is language specific... the string could be "jkdhglkejbvg", it would not matter for a programming problem...

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach Invent a good enough automated translator. Then we can speak about it. (Remark: Google Translate is not at all good enough. Not even slightly.)

Comment: @yo' as I mentioned in the second paragraph I'm already aware of it. But I will be soon in the situation to do the translations manually from Stackoverflow Original to Stackoverflow German (if the beta phase starts sometimes). So I was asking myself why not to bundle the results of me, and many other at stack exchange sites, in one place to create one awesome multinational knowledge resource...

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach because the reviews would to be too much work. It's *easier* to create a whole new community for a different language.

Comment: And it is easier to just not to participate here, but that is not an argument. On idea of my concept is to let the community benefit of that: "Further the time to get an answer in cause of the queue-passing will encourage the users to post in English.". So it is just about people like me, to provide translations, but a non proportional amount of people could profit.

Comment: Thinking further, untranslated posts could be shown only to those accepting specifically a language, so they can communicate. The problem to "identify worthable post" will solve itself: Who would do work for uninteresting posts?